# UIScrollView with "Circular" scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

I am trying to make "Circular" scrolling in my UIScrollView, but unsuccessful.

What I want to do:
if uiscrollview reaches end, it should move to start
if uiscrollview at start and moving back, it should move to end

Appending scrollview isn't good way in my situation (other methods should get "page id")

Have you any ideas?

Comment: use scroll view property Ihave  understand what have you ask.

Comment: Now I have search that I was using that in my project I think you want like left and right side one one image and backside also one image and it rotate like a horizontal circle.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've implemented this method, but it **requires paging enabled**. Lets assume you have five elements `A,B,C,D and E`. When you set up your view, you add the last element to the beginning and the first element to the end, and adjust the content offset to view the first element, like this `E,[A],B,C,D,E,A`. In the UIScrollViewDelegate, check if the user reach any of the ends, and move the offset **without** animation to the other end.

Imagine the [ ] indicates the view being shown:

```
E,A,B,C,[D],E,A
```

User swipes right

```
E,A,B,C,D,[E],A
```

User swipes right

```
E,A,B,C,D,E,[A]
```

Then, automatically set the content offset to the second element

```
E,[A],B,C,D,E,A
```

This way the user can swipe both ways creating the illusion of an infinite scroll.

```
E,A,[B],C,D,E,A
```

### Update

I've uploaded a **complete implementation** of this algorithm. It's a very complicated class, because it also has on-click selection, infinite circular scroll and cell reuse. You can use the code as is, modify it or extract the code that you need. The most interesting code is in the class `TCHorizontalSelectorView`.

[**Link to the file**](https://gist.github.com/redent/6461423)

Enjoy it!

---

### Update 2

`UICollectionView` is now the recommended way to achieve this and it can be used to obtain the very same behavior. [This tutorial](https://adoptioncurve.net/2013/07/02/building-a-circular-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/) describes in details how to achieve it.

Comment: My scroll view has paging enabled

Comment: Thank you, it's beautiful solution.

Comment: Which event should I use to go from the last element to the second?

Comment: @sMember you switch in the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` delegate method. I've added a complete example, you can use it or check how it's done.

Comment: Nice solution explained nicely :) +1

Answer (score 4):

Apple has a [Street Scroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102) demo that appears to have exactly what you want.

There's also a [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/advanced-scrollview-techniques.html#advanced-scrollview-techniques) from WWDC 2011 that demos their demo. ;) They cover infinite scrolling first in the video.

Comment: +1 Nice, but it doesn't work with paging, at least not out of the box. I tried with enabling paging, but the frame seems larger then the display. Maybe with some adjustments.

Comment: @Kai This isn't really meant for paging, and I'm not sure the OP actually ***wants*** paging. I know it's enabled, but infinite scrolling != paging. Based on his question, it sounds more like a side-scrolling game than an infinite cover flow. If it's actually paging, you could just use Apple's demo for loading a `UIPageControl` and simply modify the code to use remainder math when you are outside of your actual index zone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code..

**Sample code..**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender 
    {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
            // user is scrolling to the left from image 1 to image n(last image).
            // reposition offset to show image 10 that is on the right in the scroll view
            [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(4000,0,320,480) animated:NO];// you can define your `contensize` for scrollview
        }
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 4320) {
            // user is scrolling to the right from image n(last image) to image 1.
            // reposition offset to show image 1 that is on the left in the scroll view
            [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320,0,320,480) animated:NO];
        }
    }
```

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: Above code should work but i don't why it;s not working. than after  visit this url. It's also contain sample code >>> http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html ...

Comment: How, specifically, does this code solve the questioner's problem?

Answer (score 0):

With reference from @redent84, find the code logic.

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)

```
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(imagesArray.count), height: scrollView.frame.height)

    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

    //        imagesArray.insert(imagesArray.last as? UIImage, at: 0)
    //        imagesArray.insert(imagesArray.first as? UIImage, at: imagesArray.count - 1)


    var testArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

    let firstItem = testArr.first
    let lastItem = testArr.last

    testArr.insert(lastItem as! String, at: 0)
    testArr.append(firstItem as! String)
    print(testArr)


    for i in 0..<imagesArray.count{
        let imageview = UIImageView()
        imageview.image = imagesArray[i]
        imageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageview.clipsToBounds = true
        let xPosition = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageview.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
        print(imageview)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageview)

        print("Imageview frames of i \(i) is \(imageview.frame)")
    }

    newStartScrolling()
}

func newStartScrolling()
{
    ViewController.i += 1

    let x = CGFloat(ViewController.i) * scrollView.frame.size.width
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), animated: true)

    print("X is \(x) and i is \(ViewController.i)")

    if ViewController.i == imagesArray.count - 1 {
        ViewController.i = 0
        let x = CGFloat(ViewController.i) * scrollView.frame.size.width
        //scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), animated: false)
        print("X (rotate) is \(x) and i is \(ViewController.i)")
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = x
        self.newStartScrolling()

    }

}

func backScrolling()  {
    ViewController.i -= 1

    let x = CGFloat(ViewController.i) * scrollView.frame.size.width
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), animated: true)
    print("X is \(x) and i is \(ViewController.i)")
    if ViewController.i <= 0 {
        ViewController.i = imagesArray.count - 1
        let x = CGFloat(ViewController.i) * scrollView.frame.size.width
         scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), animated: false)
        print("X (rotate) is \(x) and i is \(ViewController.i)")

        self.backScrolling()
        //scrollView.contentOffset.x = x
        return
    }

}
```