# Smooth circular UIScrollview using auto scroll programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

Is there any way to make UIScrollview circular based on auto timer. I have some banner on home page which need to display automatic scroll.

I have added NSThread timer but when uiscroll view comes from last to first rect, it display inconsistency, which look like jump. I want to make it smooth scroll.

Comment: Take a look at the method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10448222/562990

Comment: Thanks for update but this is manually scroll not autoscroll. Manually work fine but problem in autoscroll.