# How can set circular automatic scroll view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

How to make the circular automatic scroll view, In the scrollview if the last image reached then once again start the first image continuously scrolling. Any sample source code for this task.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for image scrolling autometiculy in circular path..?

Comment: yes. Exactly I need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just create a demo of it may be its helps you this is a screen shot:-

[image]

this is a Demo link hope its helps you

http://www.sendspace.com/file/2yz9dn

Comment: can you please upload the sample once

Answer (score 0):

In the Apple documentation you can find an example about how to accomplish this, take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102), specially to the `InfiniteScrollView` class

Comment: in this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448081/uiscrollview-with-circular-scrolling) you can find other ideas about how to do it