# Give Circular Effect To Scroll View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an 20 array images. adding that images imageview that contain scroll view.scroll vertically 20 image. now my requirement is give circular effect to scroll

For Example after 20 1 2 3 4.. likewise image displayed.

I tried that one but not work for me

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    // The key is repositioning without animation
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
        // user is scrolling to the left from image 1 to image 4
        // reposition offset to show image 4 that is on the right in the scroll view
    //  [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(1280,0,320,416) animated:NO];

        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(6080, 0, 320, 416) animated:NO];

    }
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == 6400) {
        // user is scrolling to the right from image 4 to image 1
        // reposition offset to show image 1 that is on the left in the scroll view


        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,320,416) animated:NO];

        //[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

help me out this thanks in advance.

Comment: you may Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448081/uiscrollview-with-circular-scrolling ..

Comment: Anybody tell me i used that code is correct or wrong.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It might fulfill your requirement.

Comment: this will be work but not look like circle effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Apple's Sample code for circular ScrollView http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102

Otherwise

Replace your code by the following

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%f",self.scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    // The key is repositioning without animation
    if (self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
        // user is scrolling to the left from image 1 to image 4
        // reposition offset to show image 4 that is on the right in the scroll view
        //  [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(1280,0,320,416) animated:NO];

//        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(6080, 0, 320, 416) animated:NO];
         [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(6080, 0) animated:YES];
    }
    else if (self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == 6080) {
        // user is scrolling to the right from image 4 to image 1
        // reposition offset to show image 1 that is on the left in the scroll view

        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
//        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,320,416) animated:NO];

        //[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

It might help you

Comment: Instead of "scrollRectToVisible" use "setContentOffset" method.

Comment: this will work but it will not look like circle.

Comment: It will not look because we are changing here scrollview visible rect position. So better you try different code to get what you want.

Comment: iCarousel can ,i try this but i have an imageview.is this possible to add iCarousel.

Comment: please suggect me any library for adding circle effect to my scroll.

Comment: ya.. just add all the images to iCarousel with type="Rotary". you ll get circular effect. or you can try the apple sample code (that i suggest in my answer.)

Comment: but i have an imageview. i think this class not work for Imageview.

Comment: You can.. Instead of UILabel you have to take UIImageView. But for that you have to change the whole code. If you dont want to do this then try iCarousel.