# Circular scrolling in iOS that follows your finger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios7

So I am trying to figure out how to make a circular scrolling system. So I have for example a wheel like this http://static.cubiq.org/uploads/2009/04/Rotating-wheel.jpeg and you scroll between options (like an old school ipod) Now I currently already have this working with positions. So I have positions 1-6 and as you scroll down, it moves everything down a position and I animate this transition. I am wondering if there is a way to do this using the actual scroll function. So that you can scroll up and down freely while holding down, rather then doing up or down actions and waiting for animation.

So given that information how could I convert a standard vertical scroll up->down and down->up into a circle structure. Thanks for any info

Comment: You should look at using the touchesBegan/Moved/Ended calls. You can detect which button the users finger is dragging overtop and perform your animations when it enters a new button.

Comment: Check out the answers at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448081/uiscrollview-with-circular-scrolling).