# Circular ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift3

I was trying to implement circular scrollView, and I used the solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448081/uiscrollview-with-circular-scrolling?answertab=oldest#tab-top), but there was a promblem about it: scollView will switch pages in the function "scrollViewDidEndDecelerating", but there is a bug when the scrollView reached the end or the begining, and the user keeps scrolling without letting the scrollview end decelerating. Which will make it impossible to keep scrolling since the app doesn't have the time to switch from back to beginning or from beginning to back. But it will be just fine once the user stop scrolling. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you should use scrollView Did Scroll and in this check content offset of scrollview if contentOffset.x is at maximum value then scroll again to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)` to handle case where scrollview is not decelerating.

Comment: In order to switch pages, and without the user recognizing it, I have to make sure the scrollView isn't moving at all, but func "scrollViewDidEndDragging"  can't make sure of that, is there any other solutions?

Comment: @AlexBains Im not sure whats your point. But wouldnt be easier to use collection view for your purpose? Check this: https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/07/building-a-circular-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/